# How can I approve spending limit manually without having to use metamask?

Tags: metamask, evm, decentralized-exchange

[image]

[image]

When interact with smart contract on EVM chain, new token need to use "approve" function on metamask. I know this, but I have a good reason to approve the spending limit manually without having to usinmetamask. If you know how to do it, kindly drop your answer here.